# MySQL unknown column desc in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql

День добрый! Мучаюсь уже 2 день с mysql-ом. Подскажите, есть вот такой простенький запрос для удаления:

```
delete from iptv.iptv_users  where id not in (select billing.vgroups.vg_id from billing.vgroups where  billing.vgroups.tar_id=100 and  billing.vgroups.blocked=0);
```

Так вот, при выполнений пишет какую то хрень:

> `1 Unknown column 'desc' in 'where clause' SQL1.sql 2 2`

Там абсолютно нету  такого поля "desc", таблиц только вчера  создавал.
Офф сайте нашел ссылку http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=13551 но вот не хочеться верить что это баг мускуел. Как обходить ошибку ?

**UPD 1:**

Структура этих 2 таблиц:

```
CREATE TABLE `iptv_users` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `parent` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `residence_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
      `stb_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-1',
      `adress` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `login` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `pass` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `fio` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `rating` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `timezone` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `mainmenu_type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `skin_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `epg_type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `account` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `nomer_dog` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `chan_ver` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
      `vod_ver` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
      `nvod_ver` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
      `aod_ver` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
      `w_ver` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
      `adv_ver` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `hor_ver` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251 AVG_ROW_LENGTH=420

CREATE TABLE `vgroups`(
  `vg_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `cu_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `login` VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `pass` VARCHAR(128) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `agrm_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `blk_req` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'З',
  `blocked` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '',
  `changed` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '',
  `tar_id` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '',
  `shape` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '',
  `c_date` DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00' COMMENT '',
  `d_limit` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '',
  `d_clear` DATE DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '',
  `max_sessions` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT '',
  `amount` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'В',
  `current_shape` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '',
  `ip_det` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '',
   PRIMARY KEY (`vg_id`)

) ENGINE = INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT = 16148 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8 COMMENT = 'Учетные записи'
```

**UPD 2**:

`iptv.iptv_users` - Это таблица `iptv_users`, который находиться в базе iptv.

```
billing.vgroups - таблица vgroups в базе billing.
```

Comment: Попробуйте

    ...where id not in...

заменить на

    ...where iptv.iptv_users.id not in...

Comment: нет,все равно пишет ошибку..

Comment: select billing.vgroups.vg_id from billing.vgroups where  billing.vgroups.tar_id=100 and  billing.vgroups.blocked=0

этот запрос отрабатывается?

Comment: да, вот скрин:
http://xmage.ru/images/select1.png

Comment: На скрине выводится еще одна ошибка
>Unknown column '_tar_id'

billing.vgroups.vg_id и iptv.iptv_users это 2 таблицы в одной БД или 2 БД и 2 таблицы? Так для справки.

Comment: вообще то запрос в таком виде:
select billing.vgroups.vg_id from billing.vgroups where billing.vgroups.tar_id=переменная and billing.vgroups.blocked=0.
но я сейчас напрямую проверяю, подставив туда цифру 100.Не обращайте внимание на историю запросов, я просто оттуда убрал переменную.
2 таблицы с 2 баз(billing,iptv)
@Shrek,UPD: если поможеть смогу show columns выложить.

Comment: Да вообще хороший тон кидать в вопрос как можно больше нужных данных

Comment: Я в очередной раз задам
>billing.vgroups.vg_id и iptv.iptv_users это 2 таблицы в одной БД или >2 БД и 2 таблицы? Так для справки.

и второе, а если уж на то пошло то такой запрос
>delete from iptv_users  where id not in (select vgroups.vg_id from >vgroups where  vgroups.tar_id=100 and vgroups.blocked=0);

выполняется?

зачем вот это в запросе 
>iptv.
>billing.

Это префиксы чего и для чего?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так вот, как вы тащите одним запросом данные из 2х разных баз? для каждого запроса должно быть своё подключение, иначе как вы обратитесь к таблице А из базы 2, хотя в данный момент подключены к базе 1?

Я вот этот вопрос и хотел выяснить. В итоге то получается что запрос вообще косячный!

*Или какие-то запросы так вот уже выполнялись???*

//upd

Вопрос зачем полю логин 255 символов? Я вот никогда не дам пользователю более 20(это просто край! длины)

```
`login` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
```

мыло. 200 символов, это либо идиот будет региться с таким мылом либо кто? Не видел ни у одного нормального пользователя мыло более 30 символов.

```
`email` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
```

а адрес всего 50 символов, как-то странно. я в 50 символов адрес никогда не напишу. Там ведь и город и индекс и улица с домом.

```
`adress` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
```

Реально это поле для IP??? **TINYINT(1)**? или это статус какой-то?

```
`ip_det` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT '',
```

Comment: @Shrek, это вопрос разработчикам биллинговой системы http://lanbilling.ru, я просто разбираюсь в базе.

Comment: Я просто понять не могу как это работает, если 2 БД, хотя может эти БД физически лежат в одной, различаются только префиксами.